# web.xml and mixing no-auth and auth

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I would like, from a single web application, to have parts of it using authentication and parts of it to be fully open (or more specifically not use container-based auth).

The parts of the application that uses container-based authentication lives at URL `/` while the part that is open lives at URL `/openpages`. (yes, I know it would probably have been easier if it was the other way around, but don't want to open up the source code of the application)

This is my attempt at an web.xml:

```xml
<web-app>
    ....
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>closedpages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Since my *url-pattern* states `/` and not `/*` I'm thinking it should work. But it doesn't. No matter if I access `http://myhost/`  or `http://myhost/openpages/` I get HTTP Authentication prompt. Only `http://myhost/` should trigger a HTTP Authentication prompt.

The way I understand it is that everything not specifically covered by a `<security-constraint>` is open, right?   So, `/openpages/` should not use any authentication.

More to this:  I don't really like the fact that `<login-config>` is specified at the level of the webapp rather than at the level of each security constraint. Surely that is crippling to flexibility?

Comment: Could you try [whitelisting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8071539/3080094) and using an [empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36026195/3080094) for context root?

Comment: @vanOekel. This solved it for me. Especially the fact that whitelisting was an option. Why don't you put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything not specifically covered by a `security-constraint` is NOT open by default, use [whitelisting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8071539/3080094) for that (in short: a `security-constraint` without an `auth-constraint` is available to anyone without a login).

Also note that the `url-pattern` values are not entirely intuitive, see the details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36026195/3080094) and an example of a multiple url-pattern matching problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19441487/3080094) (where `/testresource.xml` matches both `/*` and `*.xml`).